# Вопрос по слайдеру

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем добрый день использую слайдер bxslider.com встала необходимость добавить активному элементу т.е слайду добавить какой либо класс. Подскажите как это сделать ??

Answer (score 1):

Если делать на примере, который указан тут:
http://bxslider.com/examples/image-slideshow-captions

то:

```
$(".bxslider li:not(:hidden)").addClass("test");
```

Где "test" нужный класс.

Comment: А если слайдер горизонтальный ?? с эфектом прокрутки ?

Comment: А в примере он по Вашему вертикальный? И без всяких эффектов?

Данный слайдер имеет общую структуру:

<ul class="bxslider">
<li><img src="..."></li>
<li><img src="...></li>
...
</ul>

Неактивные элементы li имеют display: none.

Соответственно то, что я написал выше, решает задачу добавления класса к активному элементу.

Comment: В моем случае имеется в виду слайдер этого типа http://bxslider.com/examples/manual-show-without-infinite-loop

Comment: Для этого типа так:
var liNum = Math.abs( parseInt( $(".bxslider").css("-webkit-transform").split(",")[4] ) / $(".bxslider li").width() );

$(".bxslider li:eq(" + liNum + ")").addClass("test");

В liNum попадает номер элемента li который сейчас активен (начиная с нуля).

Наверняка можно придумать что-то проще, но это первое, что пришло в голову.

Comment: Чет не работает ладно придумал другой способ буду пробовать